# How to publish image and URL on Facebook using latest facebook SDK for Android?

Tags: android, facebook, sdk, integration, publish

I want to create a Facebook dialog as shown in the last image of this [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/). But I am not able to see the default message and also not able to see the image. I wrote this code with help of this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8893331/how-to-show-the-publish-dialog-box-when-using-facebook-integration-with-android).

Here is the code for the same:

```
public void postToWall(String message) {

    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
    parameters.putString("method", "stream.publish");

    JSONObject attachment = new JSONObject();

    try {

        attachment.put("app_id", APP_ID);
        attachment.put("href", MY_URL);
        attachment.put("picture", MY_PICTURE_URL);
        attachment.put("name", NAME_FOR_URL);
        attachment.put("caption", CAPTION_FOR_URL);
        attachment.put("description", DESCRIPTION_FOR_URL);
        attachment.put("message", MESSAGE);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    parameters.putString("attachment", attachment.toString());
    facebook.dialog(this, "stream.publish",parameters, new TestUiServerListener());


    }
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this Snippet for Posting Image along with additional Details :

```
private void post_facebook() {
    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
    parameters.putString("method", "stream.publish");

    JSONObject attachment = new JSONObject();

            // for adding image to Dialog       
    try {
        JSONObject media = new JSONObject();
        media.put("type", "image");
        media.put("src", "Any Image Link");
        media.put("href", "Any Image Link");
        attachment.put("media", new JSONArray().put(media));
    } catch (JSONException e1) {
    }

            // End if Image attachment

            // for adding Message with URL link
    try {
        attachment.put("message", "Messages");
        attachment.put("name", "Check out");
        attachment.put("href", "http://www.google.com");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
    }

    parameters.putString("attachment", attachment.toString());
    authenticatedFacebook.dialog(Settings_View.this, "stream.publish",parameters, new TestUiServerListener());
}
```

Comment: Thank you venky... But I am not still able to see the default message

Comment: I mean the message sent via  - attachment.put("message", "Messages"); I am not able to see this message on the publish dialog box.. its a blank box with no message... But allows the user to type in.. I want to show the message as well as want to allow the user to type in